# take an element class and put it to another element as atribute

Tags: jquery, class, attributes

SOURCE CODE

```
<div class="level_1 euItem generation_y _2012">
    <img border="0" src="img2.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/car.htm" class="lightview">Run</a>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem youth_forum">
    <img border="0" src="img3.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/aircraft.htm" class="lightview">Run</a>
</div>
```

i need to take the third class of a div element and put it as attribute to a A element

RESULT CODE:

```
<div class="level_1 euItem generation_y _2012">
    <img border="0" src="img2.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run">
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/car.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="generation_y _2012">Run</a>
</div>

<div class="level_1 euItem youth_forum">
    <img border="0" src="img3.jpg" class="euImg">
    <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/aircraft.htm" class="lightview" alt="Run" data-lightview-group="youth_forum">Run</a>
</div>
```

i am at this point now, but it doesn't work. note that each div have a different class that i have to use:

```
var lightviewGroup = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
$('div.euBox div.level_1 h4 a.link-ico').attr('data-lightview-group',imgCaption[2]);
```

Comment: this has to be `$('div.euBox div.level_1 h4 a.link-ico')...` rather than `$(div.euBox div.level_1 h4 a.link-ico)..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//if you want to get all the classes as attribute value except for the first one
$('div.level_1').find('.lightview').attr('data-lightview-group', function () {
    return $(this).closest('.level_1')[0].className.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LUnmD/)**

```
//If you want only the last class then:
$('div.level_1').find('.lightview').attr('data-lightview-group', function () {
    return $(this).closest('.level_1')[0].className.split(" ").pop();
});
```

Results in :

```
 <div class="level_1 euItem generation_y_2012">
    <img border="0" src="img2.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run"> <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/car.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="generation_y_2012">Run</a>

</div>
<div class="level_1 euItem youth_forum">
    <img border="0" src="img3.jpg" class="euImg" alt="Run"> <a href="/sport/sport_2014/media_gallery/images/aircraft.htm" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="youth_forum">Run</a>

</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uSgUM/)**

Comment: i need one more thing, is to put those class to the A in an alphabetic order. Can you help me for this? thanks you

Answer (score 0):

To get the third class:

```
var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[2]
```

Assign it to the `<a>` element:

```
$(this).find('a.lightview').attr('data-lightview-group',cls);
```

Answer (score 0):

If last class of parent div should go as value for data-lightview-group, OP script should be updated as

`var lightviewGroup = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
$(div.euBox div.level_1 h4 a.link-ico).attr('data-lightview-group',lightviewGroup[lightviewGroup.length - 1]);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code you provided splits the class of the div into an array called `lightviewGroup` but then you use a different array called `imgCaption` to try and populate the attribute. So that is wrong to start with.

The correct version would be something like this :

```
var lightviewGroup = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
$(this).find('a').attr('data-lightview-group',lightviewGroup[2]);
```

That way you are using the correct class value and you are setting it to all of the sub `<a>` elements of the current object. (div)